# Python: Skater is showing a feature importance error. FeatureImportanceError: Something went wrong. Importances do not sum to a positive value

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, feature-selection

I am trying to find the global feature importance of a model post training by using Skater as a library.
There is an error i am getting which states as follows:

**FeatureImportanceError: Something went wrong. Importances do not sum to a positive valueThis could be due to:1) 0 or infinite divisions2) perturbed values == original values3) feature is a constant.**

I have figured out the error. 
My X variable contains a column which contains a few 0's so this is why the error is showing up.

```
model_rfr = random_search_CV(model_rfr,X_permut,Y,params_rfr,folds,
                                                          n_iter,scoring,n_jobs) #####THIS IS A CUSTOM RANDOM CV SEARCH FUNCTION THAT IS USED

estimator_rfr=model_rfr.best_estimator_ ###TAKING THE BEST MODEL OUT FROM HERE

estimator_rfr
Out[84]: 
RandomForestRegressor(bootstrap=True, criterion='mse', max_depth=3,
           max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
           min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
           min_samples_leaf=0.5, min_samples_split=0.2,
           min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=200, n_jobs=None,
           oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0, warm_start=False)

type(estimator_rfr)
Out[85]: sklearn.ensemble.forest.RandomForestRegressor

####The above part is working flawlessly

from skater import Interpretation
interpreter_rfr = Interpretation(X_permut, feature_names=np.asarray(X_permut.columns)) ###X_permut is my Dataframe

from skater.model import InMemoryModel
model1_rfr = InMemoryModel(estimator_rfr.predict,examples=X_permut, unique_values=list(X_permut.columns))

plots_2_rfr = interpreter_rfr.feature_importance.plot_feature_importance(model1_rfr, ascending=True)

plots2_Series_rfr=interpreter_rfr.feature_importance.feature_importance(model1_rfr)
```

**FeatureImportanceError: Something went wrong. Importances do not sum to a positive valueThis could be due to:1) 0 or infinite divisions2) perturbed values == original values3) feature is a constant.**

```
My X_permut Dataframe is as follows:

X_permut(34,857,5)
Out[78]: 
       Distance  BuildingArea  Lattitude  Longtitude  YearBuilt
0           2.0         160.0      -38.0       145.0          0
1           2.0         160.0      -38.0       145.0          0
2           2.0          79.0      -38.0       145.0         41
3           2.0         160.0      -38.0       145.0          0
4           2.0         150.0      -38.0       145.0         41
5           2.0         160.0      -38.0       145.0          0
6           2.0         142.0      -38.0       145.0        154
7           2.0         220.0      -38.0       145.0        146
8           2.0         160.0      -38.0       145.0         41


Y(34857,)
Out[79]: 
0        1050173.0
1        1480000.0
2        1035000.0
3        1050173.0
4        1465000.0
5         850000.0
6        1600000.0
7        1050173.0
8        1050173.0
9        1050173.0
10        941000.0
```

**I have thought of a fix is that while encoding for categorical values, i could probably start encoding from 1, bu that is something which is not possible since there are many components attached and there would be a lot of rework.
Can someone help me with this with an alternative??**

Comment: So for this. I had used a quick fix. Either we normalize the data for X_permut or I had used X_permut=X_permut.replace(0,0.00001), the latter having more chances of running smoothly.